# Codeigniter too many requst csrf ajax

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-3

Currently, I am developing with Codeigniter. Inside my Codeigniter, there are 15 ajax request calls. Every time there is a request, it updates csrf token value. The problem is when it request more than 15 times, it gives '403 Forbidden' error.

Is there a limit within Codeigniter? If there is, how do I remove this limit?
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no such limit. You're just not keeping track of CSRF token updates.

Each time you submit a POST request, CodeIgniter will re-generate its CSRF token and send it back as the new CSRF cookie value in the response.
If you don't update your pre-generated forms (or other types of ajax request data) with the new value, they'll still have the old token and fail validation.

You can disable regeneration altogether by setting `$config['csrf_regenerate'] = false;` in your config/config.php file, but this is discouraged. The proper thing to do is to keep track of the token changes.

Comment: I am requesting every second. Does the error happen when the time creating csrf token is longer than one second?

Comment: No ... It's not about time, it's about synchronization (that you don't have).

Comment: I have disabled csrf_regenerate for now. I assume that if csrf_regernate is disabled, creating csrf is not meaningful.

Thank you for the comment.